# How to partition postgres table using intermediate table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I am using postgres 10 db.

I am having Customers table consisting of following columns

```
custid (primary key),
name,
phonenumber,
email,
dateofbirth,
address,
city,
country,
status(boolean)
Join_Date(Date)
```

I have million of records in table. I want to partition table based on different months(Jan 2018 one partition, Feb 2018 one partition,..etc) by help of Join_Date and with help of Intermediate table.

I also want to write the automated script such that at the end of month the table have to get create another partition of last month

Comment: so what actually you want to do

Comment: i want to partition customer table with the help of intermediate(temp) table

Comment: like jan 2018 one partition, feb 2018 one partition

Comment: does it physical partition or logical?

Comment: logical partition

Comment: what data will be in your intermediate table, give the structure

Comment: means like have to get jan 2018 data in intermediate table and then partition table for jan 2018 using intermediate table, then clear intermediate table and next get feb data in intermediate table and then partition feb 2018 data ... so on

Comment: ok, got it, so it'll be the same as customer table right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: and i want to write automated script or function to execute at end of month and to create partition for last month data

Comment: i have referred this https://blog.heroku.com/handling-very-large-tables-in-postgres-using-partitioning, but didn't got clarity

Comment: check my answer and do let me know if you understand the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

1. First of all, create an additional column in customer table as you
   want to logical partition.
2. Then update that columns using customer
   and intermediate table
3. After updating truncate your table

For each month you can run this script and this will give you logical partitioning.

```
update customer set partition_column=to_char(Join_Date, 'YYYY-MM')
join intermediate_table on intermediate_table.custid=customer.custid
and  intermediate_table.Join_Date=customer.Join_Date

truncate table intermediate_table
```

Comment: can you please eloborate your answer because i am very new to postgres

Comment: this applicable for all database not particularly postgres

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for your problem in the Postgres documentation.

[PostgreSQL: Documentation: 10: 5.10. Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)