# postgres: ERROR: column "catcode" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.2

I have a postgress table called catcodes. When I do

```
select Catcode from catcodes;
```

It gives me an error like this

```
ERROR:  column "catcode" does not exist
LINE 1: select Catcode from catcodes;
```

when I describe the table there is a column Catcode.

Column    |       Type        |

-------------+-------------------+

Catcode     | character varying |

```
select * from catcodes
```

works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is case-sensitive, you should try using quotes

```
SELECT "Catcode" FROM catcodes;
```

[sql - Postgres Case Sensitivity - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796446/postgres-case-sensitivity)

Comment: Thanks, It works. But could you please tell me why is that.

Comment: I managed to found more explanations ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/3824894))

Comment: please can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51758821/6633337