# Conditional Select in PostgreSQL without if-else statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
|--------|----------------|-------------|
|  url   |   description  |  for_region |
|--------|----------------|------------ |
| url1   |   desc1        |  All        |
| url2   |   desc2        |  All        |
| url2   |   desc3        | Germany     |
|--------|----------------|-------------|
```

Now I am trying to write the following query without if else statements:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table where for_country='Germany') THEN
   select * from my_table where for_country='Germany'
ELSE 
   select * from my_table where for_country='All'
END IF;
```

What is the best way to rewrite the above query without the use of if-else statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `EXISTS` into the `WHERE` clause

```
select * 
from my_table 
where (EXISTS (select 1 from my_table where for_country='Germany') and for_country='Germany') OR
      (NOT EXISTS (select 1 from my_table where for_country='Germany') and for_country='All')
```

[DBFiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6e420b145539a032c730ee30c86e2be1)

and a probably better solution is to use `EXISTS` and `CROSS JOIN` to avoid the duplicate call of the same subquery

```
select my_table.* 
from my_table 
cross join (
  select exists(select 1 from my_table where for_country='Germany') exst
) t
where (t.exst and for_country='Germany') OR
      (not t.exst and for_country='All')
```

[DBFiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=451fc5939cb6a2684ab915b23d2ff546)

Comment: please can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51758821/6633337

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select m1.name from
   (
    select m1.*, case when m1.for_region='Germany' then 1  else 0  end  as cnt from tableA m1 ) m1
     inner join 
    (
    select max(Cnt) as Cnt from
    (
     select t1.*, case when for_region='Germany' then 1  else 0  end  as Cnt 
      from tableA t1
     ) as t2

     )as n 
     on m1.cnt=n.Cnt
```

Comment: please can have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51758821/6633337

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from my_table 
where 
((SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM my_table where for_country='Germany') = 1 AND for_country='Germany')
OR for_country='All'
```

Comment: please can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51758821/6633337

Answer (score 0):

I would use `UNION` with `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE for_country = 'Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE for_country = 'All' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE for_country = 'Germany');
```

Comment: please can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51758821/6633337

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select t.*
from my_table t.
where (for_country = 'Germany') or
      (not exists (select 1 from my_table where for_country = 'Germany') and
       for_country = 'All'
      );
```

Comment: please can you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51758821/6633337